# Amazon S3 Buckets content deletion script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've got a amazon S3 server that is connected to Simple DB.
in this server I've got different buckets, now, since i'm limited in space i need to delete some content from this buckets from time to time.
This deletion needs to be done for specific buckets and based to date (nothing older then a week), of course the deletion needs to be done in both of the server and the DB, 
and to run as a scheduled task in the server (the server is Windows server 2008 + SQL 2008 R2)

Can anyone suggest a script (Any language will be ok) for doing this task ?

Answer (score 0):

For S3 objects, you can use the S3 lifecycle feature to "expire" (delete) the objects when it crosses a specific age: [Object Expiration - Amazon Simple Storage Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html)

I am not aware of such a convenient way to do this on Simple DB. You might have to write a periodic script using Simple DB API do delete stuff on interval.